# Advanced Find & Replace Sublime

Tags: replace, sublimetext2

Using the Sublime Text editor, I have over 100 test methods in a Java class. I am hoping to track down the order of these tests manually (as in Java 8 with JUnit, they're random). Instead of going through 100+ tests and adding in a System.out.print(), I would like to search for all instances of:

```
@Test
public void METHODNAME() {
```

Where `METHODNAME` can be anything. I know of multiline-editing in Sublime and am pretty comfortable with many of the advanced "find-and-replace" features, but I am not aware of any "find" command that allows a certain pattern of words rather than an exact replica.

Comment: Isn't tjere a regex find and replace?

Comment: you need to use the regex option in the Find dialog

Comment: Could you provide an example? Possibly as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a suitable regex like: `(@Test\npublic void (.)*)`
2. Click on `Find > Replace...` or press `CTRL + H`
3. Paste the regex in "Find What:"
4. Past your replacement in "Replace With:" like e.g.: `$1 \n System.out.println("test");`

Note: The `$1` will preserve what your regex found, so you can insert code *after* your method declaration.

This example works for a file like the this:

```
@Test
public void aaa() {
aaaaaa
}

@Test
public void bbb() {
bbbbbb
}
```

After I click "Replace All" I got:

```
@Test
public void aaa() { 
 System.out.println("test");
aaaaaa
}

@Test
public void bbb() { 
 System.out.println("test");
bbbbbb
}
```